# What does “packing heat” mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, slang

I believe it means “to carry a weapon”, but I would also like the phrase origins, if possible. So the full question is:

What is the meaning of the phrase “packing heat” and what are its origins?

Comment: You may also find it interesting to know that "It's crackers to slip a rozzer the dropsy in snide."

Comment: @mickeyf: obviously (and as intended by you), I've absolutely no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, I really had no idea another phrase from the same sub-culture would be that obscure. I take for granted the idioms I grew up with. Try this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magersfontein_Lugg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Heat/heater* is slang for "gun" ([definition #14](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heat)) and *to pack* has an informal meaning "to carry, deliver, or have available for action" ([v. tr. definition #8](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pack)).  So "packing heat" means that you are carrying a gun (and are ready to use it).

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, here is the first citation for this phrase:

> 1932 W. R. BURNETT Silver Eagle i. 7 ‘He don't even pack a heater.’ ‘Don't what?’ ‘He don't carry a gun.’

And the first citation I see that uses *heat* instead of *heater* (from an old dictionary):

> 1942 L. V. BERREY & M. VAN DEN BARK Amer. Thes. Slang §496/6 Pack (a) heat,..to carry a gun.

Answer (score 5):

EtymOnline [offers this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pack):

> Sense of "to carry or convey in a pack" (1805) led to general sense of "to carry in any manner;" hence *to pack heat* "carry a gun," underworld slang from 1940s.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few examples in Google Books of "pack a heater" earlier than the OED's 1932.

*The Golden book magazine*: Volume 10, No. 57, September [1929](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=TBVrT8XLMuTP4QSL7PGWBg&id=cLvmAAAAMAAJ&dq=%E2%80%9Cpack%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacking%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%20%E2%80%9Cpacks%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacked%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D&q=%22since%20reading%22#search_anchor):

> Since reading *Little Caesar* we chat lightly with gangmen about **packing a heater (carrying a gun)**, or getting the book for a caper (a life sentence for a murder). . . . The surprising thing about this book of WR Burnett's is that there are three hundred-odd pages of this slang set in prose as staccato as the frequent machine-gun fine, and yet it manages to be an excellent novel.

[Burnett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._R._Burnett) "is best known for the crime novel *Little Caesar* [1929], whose film adaptation [1931] is considered the first of the classic American gangster movies." The OED 1932 is from Burnett's *Silver Eagle*.

*Al Capone: biography of a self-made man* by Fred D. Pasley, [1930](http://books.google.fi/books?id=gxU4AAAAIAAJ&q=%E2%80%9Cpack%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacking%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%20%E2%80%9Cpacks%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacked%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D&dq=%E2%80%9Cpack%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacking%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%20%E2%80%9Cpacks%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacked%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TBVrT8XLMuTP4QSL7PGWBg&redir_esc=y):

> And **he never packed a heater**, as do many Chicago police reporters. He was abstemious. A glass of beer was his limit. Gambling was a consuming fever with him. It debilitated his moral being. It enslaved him like a drug.

*Scribner's magazine: Volume 87*, 1930:

> Felix stood looking from Mary to Oregon, fascinated, unable to move. “Fast rambler, yeah,” said Mary. “Tough guy. Picks on old 'boes that can't lift a hand and **him packing a heater**. Yeah, tough guy.

And in fact the OED's Burnett citation appears to have also been printed in a magazine a year before, in *Collier's: Volume 87*, [1931](http://books.google.fi/books?id=viEfAQAAMAAJ&q=%E2%80%9Cpack%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacking%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%20%E2%80%9Cpacks%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacked%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D&dq=%E2%80%9Cpack%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacking%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%20%E2%80%9Cpacks%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D%20OR%20%E2%80%9Cpacked%20a%20heater%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TBVrT8XLMuTP4QSL7PGWBg&redir_esc=y):

> ”Yeah, but it’s just a stall. **He don't even pack a heater.**"
>   "Don't what?"
>   "He don't carry a gun. It's all a bluff. It's the old run-around."