# First use of “packing” as in carrying a gun

Tags: etymology

A friend is using the sentence, “Nobody was packing there,” in an historical novel set in the 1885-90 timeframe.

I suspect “packing” was not used in this slang format until 30-40 years later?

Does anyone have corroboration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “packing heat” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/what-does-packing-heat-mean)

Comment: Thanks for the question. Without more context, any answer needs qualification. For example,  "The pack horses had to be left outside of town while the men went on in. *Nobody was packing there.*" gives one context for your friend's sentence, but "In Carson City [in the 1890s] men packing a pistol were hung for being dangerous cowards. *Nobody was packing there.*" gives quite another. Neither use would be anachronistic in a historical novel set in the 1890s.

Comment: Note also that in the 1890s another idiom was in use: 'packing a [weapon] for [somebody]' meant that the weapon was being carryed for the purpose or with the intent of using it on the indirect object (somebody). The weapon involved was generally a knife or gun.

Comment: It may be worth comparing to "packs a punch", which seems to have been newish in 1912, where it appears in scare quotes. https://books.google.com/books/content?id=LUYlAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA20&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3WoD4DQhB_L0cBg9D33IpH90QDfg&ci=89%2C1256%2C416%2C156&edge=0

Answer (score 5):

from [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pack) **pack**

> Sense of "to carry or convey in a pack" (1805) led to general sense of
>   "to carry in any manner;" hence to pack heat "carry a gun,"

and [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/135833#eid32383603)

> 1865   Atlantic Monthly One of the best of Rosecrans's scouts..lost
>   his life because he would..‘**pack**’ (carry) his gun.

Comment: Where did you dig up the _Atlantic Monthly_ quote? It didn’t show up in a COHA collocation search.

Comment: You can find the entire October 1865 _Atlantic_ quote [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TxwxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA435&dq=%22One+of+the+best+of+Rosecrans%27s+scouts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfoM2QpszhAhWPsJ4KHZWwCxYQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22One%20of%20the%20best%20of%20Rosecrans's%20scouts%22&f=false). Interestingly, the context involves a "scout" from eastern Kentucky working for the U.S. army who was found out by southern troops in the Confederate army because his dialect and habits differed from those of soldiers who really were from the mountains of Alabama, as he claimed to be.

Comment: Also of interest, from deposition taken March 19, 1869, from Andrew Hampton in [Barnes vs. Adams](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXFBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA207&dq=%22packed+a+gun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wt-1qczhAhXGjp4KHZfcATMQ6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=%22packed%20a%20gun%22&f=false): "Q. Did you never carry a gun, and go in company with Union soldiers ; and were you ever in the service as a soldier? — A. I have **packed a gun** to try to protect myself and my property, and to try to keep these men from stealing my property. I never was a soldier in any army."

Answer (score 5):

*Packing* meaning to carry a firearm is a shortened form of *packing a gun/pistol etc.*, which emerges in the Western and Southwestern states and territories at least by the 1870s:

> We should be glad to see William out of his troubles but he must quit “[*packing a pistol*](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86076199/1873-05-14/ed-1/seq-2/)” and playing fighter. — *Carson Daily Appeal* (Carson City NV), 14 May 1873.
>
> Q. The other men who came up, what did they come up for? —A. I didn’t see them until they got right up there. 
>   Q. Did they have anything in their hands? —A. They were [*packing guns*](https://archive.org/details/modocwarmessagef00unit/page/145?q=%22packing+guns%22). — *Modoc War*, US House of Representatives,  Message from the President [Grant], Washington DC, 1874.

The quotation marks around the phrase in the Nevada newspaper suggests a fairly new usage.

I suspect that the shortened form, i. e., with no direct object, is a late 20th c. innovation:

> The brothers were [*packing*](https://books.google.de/books?id=zUtCAAAAIAAJ&q=packed+gun&dq=packed+gun&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitzIj-lczhAhWQZVAKHay1DhAQ6AEIOzAF), but that was not unusual; the Party was under surveillance at the time because of the fear of us starting trouble in Oakland after Dr. King's death … — Earl Anthony, *Picking Up the Gun: a Report on the Black Panthers*, 1970, 107.

Your friend is safe using *pack a pistol etc.*, but it would be wise not to use the verb without a direct object for a narrative set in the late 19th c.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest instance related to "packing a gun" that I've been able to find is this one, from a poem titled "[St. Valentines day](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=SJO18520216.2.176&txq=%2522packed+a+gun%2522)," in the *[Springfield] Illinois Journal* (February 16, 1852):

> Then the second notion was, to save so much runnin / Arter the gals, which 'pays'—about as well as 'gunnin'— / Which don't pay at all, if you never tried it, take my word for it; / For, in my day, I've **'packed' a gun** until I fairly abhor it.

I agree with KarlG's conclusion that "packing"—without "a gun," "a pistol," or "a weapon"—in the sense of carrying a firearm, and in particular a handgun—is a much later development. I suspect that his discovery of a 1970 instance of such usage will be hard to beat.

Comment: Green provides a 1962 citation to Yablonski, [*The Violent Gang*](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9781440144622) (the link is to the 2009 edition, but I checked the 1962 edition and found the same uses; see pp. 100, 114, 122; contextual evidence suggests the uses were in the early 1950s for at least 'packed'--"Chino was 'packed.'"). Given the prevalence of anti-packing sentiment associated with "pistol-packing", "packing a gun", etc. in 1890s cities, it seems ill-advised to rule out elliptical uses such as are evidenced in Yablonski.

Comment: @JEL: The book is waitlisted so I can’t access it, but does the book cite the usage generally, or particular gang members. If the latter, were they African American? I'm  wondering if the omission of object first occurred in AAVE.

Comment: @JEL: Your point about elliptical use seems very reasonable—especially in a situation where some form of "packing a [weapon]" appears nearby. Two related modern usages (at least in the United States) involve "carrying" (money [1930s+], weapons [1930s+], or drugs [1940s+]) and "holding" (drugs [1930s+] or money [1930s+]). The dates are from Green, but they appear to involve use of the words unattached to an explicit object; as with "packing," forms of the expression that include an explicit object go back to the nineteenth century, Green says.

Comment: @KarlG, particular gang members are quoted, or paraphrased using their slang. About the members, I couldn't say what their backgrounds were; the gangs were mixed, reflecting the neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2):

1898:

> He passed in between his horse and that of his son's, "and got on the
>   west side of my son, and said to him: 'You are packing a gun for me,
>   and now, then, God damn you, use it' " At this, witness wheeled his
>   horse, and jumped off.

[The Southwestern Reporter, June 27 -- August 22, 1898](https://books.google.com/books?id=-RoLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA410&dq=%22packing+a+gun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3yOrE-cvhAhUFvZ4KHcRhBSYQ6AEIUjAH#v=onepage&q=%22packing%20a%20gun%22&f=false)

Ngram finds one earlier use of "packing a gun", but it appears to refer to loading a cannon.

Comment: OP thinks that *packing* meaning "carrying a gun".

Comment: @Ubihatt - And that is the sense that the above quote appears to be using.

Comment: I always thought it was just short for _packing heat_.

Comment: @KarlG yep! you are correct. Packing heat means carrying a gun.

Comment: @Ubihatt - I don't understand.  If you read the context (click on the link) the quote clearly refers to *carrying* a gun.  "Packing heat" didn't enter the argot until the 1980s.

Comment: hmm...without context *packing* does not mean *carrying a gun.* Just check the OP's sentence: `Nobody was packing there.` OP thinks that *packing* means *carrying a gun.* I guess, OP is confusing *packing* with *packing heat*. Anyways, good search!

Comment: @Ubihatt - OP implies (with "this slang format") that the meaning in his context is "carrying a gun".  If you don't believe that's the case you should ask him to clarify his question.

Comment: @HotLicks okay okay!